# ¿Cómo hago que ciertos puntos no se incluyan en la gráfica?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, cluster, plot

Estoy realizando clustering de una serie de datos, y quería que los outliers no se dibujaran en el gráfico.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.005, min_samples=20).fit(X)
labels = db.labels_

n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
n_noise_ = list(labels).count(-1)

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines(resolution="10m")
ax.add_feature(cfeature.RIVERS)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
ax.gridlines()
ax.set_extent([-6, -4, 35.5, 37], ccrs.PlateCarree())

plt.scatter(X["lon"], X["lat"],
        c=labels,
        s=10,
        alpha=1,
        transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

Los outliers son los que tienen la etiqueta (en el array "labels") igual a -1, y el color que se les asigna es el morado que se aprecia a lo largo de todo el mapa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Publica la gráfica para mejor entender el problema.

Comment: Añadido el gráfico

Comment: Hola buenas yo que tu invocaba al dragon de fuego para que se los comiese y pisto de papeles

Answer (score 1):

Al final conseguí eliminar los outliers de la siguiente manera:

```
X["labels"] = labels
X = X.drop(X[X["labels"] == -1].index)
Y = X.reset_index(drop=True)
labels = X["labels"]
X = X.drop(["labels"], axis=1)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: así lo hubiera hecho yo si, me parece sumamente correcto y apropiado